# power automate flow excel table keys or columns

Tags: excel, key, power-automate

How do you get a list of the Table columns/keys from a Table in an EXCEL file, in a One Drive folder. I am probably using incorrect terms - apologies. I am already successfully using "List rows present in Table" - when column names are already known. But ... in my current task, the Table columns/keys are unknown and need to be listed.
Thanks for your patience.
Kevin.

Comment: Try using Stack exchange or super user. Those will be better suited for this type of question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67868270/how-to-fetch-specific-column-data-from-xls-in-microsoft-flow

Comment: the post above in the stackoverflow link has the solution .. but ... the solver didnt reveal the content of the variable initialization  : (   ... I just need to find out what is meant by "assign your column name dynamically"

Comment: so .. this post is a duplicate and can be deleted.